# Using a DLL to connect to a device: Unmanaged resource or not

Tags: c#, dll, .net-3.5, unmanaged, managed

In C# I am using a DLL to connect to an ePad device (Wacom). I know that managed resources are the ones that are managed by the garbage collector and the rest are unmanaged.

I have a class from which I use this DLL to connect and communicate with the ePad device and I am not sure if it is really an unmanaged resource or not. I want to be sure if it is an unmanaged resource. If so, I want to implement IDisposable in the class where I am using this DLL to release resources and unsubscribe from device events.

So the question is: is it unmanaged or managed?

Comment: If the DLL is no .NET assembly, it is (very, very likely) unmanaged. Try to open the DLL in ILDASM and it will tell you.

Comment: @KlausGütter Ok, and how can I know if it is not a .NET assembly? Do I have to pay attention to something once opened with ILDASM? I can open it using ILDASM.

Comment: Then it is a .NET assembly. So this quick test could not reveal if unmananged resources are involved.

Comment: Ok, and what would be the next step to carry on in order to confirm that It is an unmanaged resource?

Comment: @KlausGütter Ok, and what would be the next step to carry on in order to confirm that It is an unmanaged resource?

Comment: Ist there some documentation of the library? Rule of thumb: if any object you get from the library implements IDisposable, dispose it when done with it.